# Using shapely geometry to expand a rotated rectangle

Tags: python, computational-geometry, shapely

I'm currently using python's shapely geometry package for polygons computations. Mostly what I'm using are rectangles. I define a rectangle as:
`Polygon([(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)])`

My question is how to scale or expand a rotated rectangle. For example, say I want to add 10 to the left side, 20 to the right, 30 to the top, and 40 to the bottom side.

A non-rotated rectangle is easy. Assuming x1=x2, x3=x4, y2=y3, and y4=y1, I could just add the additional amounts to the proper coordinates and the rectangle would be expanded. My question is how about a rotated rectangle, like this:
[image: Fig 1.]

This rectangle was defined as `Polygon([(0,10), (10,20), (20,10), (10,0)])`.
How can I project the upper left side by 10 points (i.e. increase the length of the bottom left and top right lines by 10 points while keeping the same rotation and origin)?

I initially tried using affinity.scale, but the problem there is it expands only along an axis, not along a rotated axis, so the rectangle ends up skewed.

The only other option I could think of was to calculate the angle of rotation, de-rotate the rectangle, add the extensions to the appropriate coordinates, then rotate the rectangle back to its original rotation. This seems like a lot of steps, and also, I'm worried the final rectangle might be shifted in the x or y axis (since de-rotating, expanding, and re-rotating might not end up on the same original axis if the center of the rectangle is now different i.e. the amounts added to opposite ends of the rectangle is not symmetric.)

Is there any built-in function that scales along an arbitrary axis, or a formula to do it correctly?

Comment: This is not a rotated rectangle, it is a diamond.